# Is there a way to see if or how much of your reputation is based on deleted items?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

For example, I answered a question, and my answer received one up-vote and one down-vote, so my net gain in reputation was 8. Turns out, my answer was, in fact, less than ideal, so I deleted my answer. Now, my reputation still reflects that net gain of 8 points, but my daily activity no longer shows the up-vote and the down-vote. Is there a way to see this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it using reputation page.

Add /reputation to your url. It will show summary of current reputation.

It would not show you reputation lost for deleted posts, but if there is any difference from your current rep and the number shown in that page, then you will know that difference is because of the deleted posts.

Answer (score 3):

Go to /reputation page, scroll down and find total rep ...., and diff with current rep.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any way to get to this page from the UI?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo, as far as I know for now, that page is not linked in anywhere at UI.